# how to run mysql query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to transform my MySql query into a Query in Laravel but I really don't know how to do this. I don't know how to rename in FROM like in SQL

My query is the following one :

```
SELECT f2.* FROM formation f2 WHERE f2.theme_id IN 
(SELECT f.theme_id FROM user_formation uf JOIN formation f ON uf.formation_id = f.id WHERE uf.user_id = 2) 
AND f2.id NOT IN 
(SELECT formation_id FROM user_formation WHERE user_id = 2);
```

I tried something like this but ...

```
$q = Formation::query()
                ->from('formation AS f2')
                ->whereIn('f2.theme_id', function($r)
                {
                    $r->select('f.theme_id')->from('user_formation AS uf')
                    ->join('formation', function($join)
                    {
                        $join->on('uf.formation_id', '=', 'f.id')
                        ->where ('uf.user_id', '=', $id)
                    });
                });

            ->whereNotIn('f2.id', function($s){
                $s->select('formation.id')
                ->from('user_formation')
                ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
            })->get();
```

thanks for help.

Comment: you can run this in "raw", or with "query builder". Which of these two do you want?

Comment: i prefer query builder cause I never used raw for now, and don't know how it works.

Comment: well the raw I mean just like using `mysqli_query` or something like that. Well from the code you given, is it error? Or something? What's wrong?

Comment: with my $q, I actually got a syntax error with } but I don't know where cause everything is close to my mind, and I don't know if I can do this "->from('formation AS f2') " with Laravel

Comment: you don't need `from`, you don't need alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this raw query you can run:

```
$res = DB::select('
  SELECT f2.* 
  FROM formation f2 
  WHERE f2.theme_id IN 
    (SELECT f.theme_id FROM user_formation uf JOIN formation f ON uf.formation_id = f.id WHERE uf.user_id = 2) 
    AND f2.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT formation_id FROM user_formation WHERE user_id = 2)');
```

Or you can rewrite this query in laravel query builder Eloquent ORM:

```
Formations::query()
  ->whereIn('formations.theme_id', function($q){
      $user_formations_table = (new UserFormation)->getTable();
      $formation_table = (new Formation)->getTable();
      $q->select('paper_type_id')
        ->from($user_formations_table)
        ->join($formation_table, "$user_formations_table.formation_id", '=', "$formation_table.id")
        ->where("$user_formations_table.user_id", 2);
  })->whereNotIn('formations.id', function($q){
      $user_formations_table = (new UserFormation)->getTable();
      $q->select('formation_id')
        ->where("$user_formations_table.user_id", 2);
  })
  ->get();
```

> Note that I have used models `Formations`, `UserFormation`, `Formation` Because you have used 3 different tables, you should add this models and specify tables to run ORM query

I advice to run first RAW query if there is no another need to run it with Eloquent

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for your help, the RAW query is working well, I didn't know we could just set a SQL query in Laravel, that's great. I want to understand something with Eloquent, in which process consist this line `$user_formations_table = (new UserFormation)->getTable();`

Comment: That gives you table name from model. If you have specified `public $table = 'tablename'` returns `tablename`, if you don't have specified then it returns plurar form of model name

Comment: okay, so if u want to use formation f2, and formation f, this is a good way to use  tables with different names ?

Comment: No, you can get table name once and then label it as you want. You can hardcode table name too but it's bad practice to do so

Comment: okay thanks, I didn't understand the Eloquent version very well, but that was very helpful !

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fix your code indentations so you don't confuse yourself. Second, you placed semicolon in the wrong places. Third, you need to pass `$id` inside function because of the variable scope.

```
$q = Formation::query()
    ->whereIn('f2.theme_id', function($r) use ($id) {
        $r->select('f.theme_id')->from('user_formation AS uf')
            ->join('formation', function($join) use ($id) {
                $join->on('uf.formation_id', '=', 'f.id')
                ->where('uf.user_id', '=', $id);
            }
        );
    })
    ->whereNotIn('f2.id', function($s) use ($id) {
        $s->select('formation.id')
        ->from('user_formation')
        ->where('user_id', '=', $id);
    })->get();
```

Note : If you are using VSCode, I suggest to use PHP Intelephense as it will help with autocomplete, syntax check, etc.

Comment: thanks, I know about the $id, I was just showing with an exemple, actually I have a $id which takes the id of the authentified user so the result is adapted for each one. I'm actually using Sublime Text, sorry for the code indentations, I'm normally more serious with it. my bad.